# GNU MIX Development Kit build error

Tags: compiling, assembly

I am trying to compile [the GNU MIX assembly development kit](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/mdk/) on Mac OS X 10.8.4. I've installed the dependencies through homebrew, and when I run `configure` in the mdk directory, I get a success message:

```
*** GNU MDK 1.2.7 has been successfully configured. ***

Type 'make' to build the following utilities:
    - mixasm (MIX assembler)
    - mixvm (MIX virtual machine)
```

But when I run `make`, It spits out this error:

```
~/Downloads/mdk-1.2.7 > make
make  all-recursive
Making all in po
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in intl
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in doc
Making all in img
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
Making all in lib
rm -f libreplace.a
ar cru libreplace.a
ar: no archive members specified
usage:  ar -d [-TLsv] archive file ...
  ar -m [-TLsv] archive file ...
  ar -m [-abiTLsv] position archive file ...
  ar -p [-TLsv] archive [file ...]
  ar -q [-cTLsv] archive file ...
  ar -r [-cuTLsv] archive file ...
  ar -r [-abciuTLsv] position archive file ...
  ar -t [-TLsv] archive [file ...]
  ar -x [-ouTLsv] archive [file ...]
make[2]: *** [libreplace.a] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It looks like `ar` is failing, although I don't know why. How can I debug this further?